# Navigation properties in domain classes without EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

My `ElementGroup` class has an `Elements` property, which is of type `List<Element>`. To enable navigation back to its parent `ElementGroup`, my `Element` class has an `ElementGroup` property, which is of type `ElementGroup`. Usually I would set this up using navigation properties in Entity Framework, but I wanted to temporarily set this up in my domain layer before I add my data layer. How is this done?

This approach seems to work, but it requires a local variable for my `ElementGroup` object:

```
ElementGroup eg = new ElementGroup("Dummy Name", 100);
competition.ElementGroups.Add(eg);
eg.Elements.Add(new Element(new DateTime(2014, 9, 14, 12, 0, 0)) { ElementGroup = eg });
eg.Elements.Add(new Element(new DateTime(2014, 9, 14, 13, 0, 0)) { ElementGroup = eg });
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without creating a local variable by doing something like this:

```
competition.ElementGroups.Add(new ElementGroup("Dummy Name", 100)
{
  Elements = new List<Element> {
    new Element(new DateTime(2014, 9, 14, 12, 0, 0)) { },
    new Element(new DateTime(2014, 9, 14, 13, 0, 0)) { }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure how to assign the current `ElementGroup` to the new `Element`'s `ElementGroup` property using object initializer curly braces or using some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AddElement` method in `ElementGroup`:

```
public Element AddElement(DateTime datetime)
{
    var element = new Element(datetime) { ElementGroup = this };
    this.Elements.Add(element);
    return element;
}
```

Comment: How would this method be used in the application code? For example, let's say I wanted to add one ElementGroup and three Elements in a single statement (without creating a local variable).

Comment: Why is a single statement so important to you? I don't see how you can create objects with mutual references without at least one local variable.

Comment: It's important because I'm trying to learn and when I was writing the code I had a feeling that there was probably a more elegant way to do what I was trying to do.